# Is there a function which can replace "zip" function in Python?

Tags: python, list, iterator, zip

In Python , as we all know there is a useful function : zip
for instance:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [5,4,3,2,1]
```

we can "add" these lists in one line:

```
c = [ x[0] + x[1] for x in zip(a,b) ]
```

But it seems zip created a new list.
In many cases , which I want is just a pair of data( a[i],b[i] ) , I don't want the "zip" list at all.

In c# , we can make a iterator to get pair data from a and b , so we could avoid to make a new "zip" list.

What about python?

Comment: Not to your question, but I think there are clearer ways to write `[x[0] + x[1] for x in zip(a,b)]`.  `[sum(x) for x in zip(a,b)]` is clearer but slower, and `[x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)]` is clearer and faster.  (Of course, clarity is in the eye of the beholder.)

Comment: Yea, I absolutely agreed with you. And I'll change my behavior while writing codes about zip/izip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [`itertools.izip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>   Like zip() except that it returns an iterator instead of a list. Used
>   for lock-step iteration over several iterables at a time.

Example:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [5,4,3,2,1]
>>> c = izip(a, b)
>>> c
<itertools.izip object at 0x10d1aaf38>
>>> for x, y in c:
...     print x, y
... 
1 5
2 4
3 3
4 2
5 1
```

Note that in Python-3.x `izip()` is gone, [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that in python3.x, `itertools.izip` goes away and regular `zip` returns an iterable object rather than a `list`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a function per se, just use a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [5,4,3,2,1]

for pair in ((a[i], b[i]) for i in xrange(min(len(a), len(b)))):
    print pair
```

Output:

```
(1, 5)
(2, 4)
(3, 3)
(4, 2)
(5, 1)
```

Comment: -0.  You do answer the question but this is both ugly and unnecessary because `itertools.izip` exists.  I like that you mentioned generator expressions.

Comment: @Steven: Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

## Generator for fixed or variable number of iterables

You may create your own generator in Python too:

```
def mygen(a, b):
    """generator yielding values from two iterables"""
    aiter = iter(a)
    biter = iter(b)
    while True:
        yield aiter.next(), biter.next()

def dyngen(*iterables):
    """generator for yielding list from dynamic number of iterables"""
    iterables = map(iter, iterables)
    while True:
        yield  map(next, iterables)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    b = [5,4,3,2,1]
    c = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

    gen = mygen(a, b)
    print gen.next()
    print gen.next()
    print gen.next()
    print gen.next()
    print gen.next()

    print "dyngen"
    gen = dyngen(a, b, c)
    print gen.next()
    print gen.next()
    print gen.next()
    print gen.next()
    print gen.next()
```

Calling from command line:

```
$ python myzip.py 
(1, 5)
(2, 4)
(3, 3)
(4, 2)
(5, 1)
dyngen
[1, 5, 'a']
[2, 4, 'b']
[3, 3, 'c']
[4, 2, 'd']
[5, 1, 'e']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use map() as below:

```
c = map(lambda x,y:x+y,a,b)
```

Comment: This doesn't avoid the problem since ```map(None,a,b)``` returns a list (in fact, the same list as ```zip```)

Comment: you're right, I re-edit it with lambda function now.

Comment: @wnnmaw -- I agree with your point, but there is a very subtle difference when the 2 iterables are of different length -- `zip` truncates to the shorter whereas on python2.x, `map` pads the shorter with `None`.

Comment: @mgilson yes, it has different behavior when len of two lists are different, wnnmaw is right about my original answer, I re-edit it now.

Comment: @mgilson, good catch! Though I think the issue is more that the result shouldn't be a list