# zip function in python for lists

Tags: python, list, function, zip

If I use the zip function than I am not getting the desired output. I want to combine two lists which are as follows:-
list1 = []
list2 = [0]

I want the output as [0].
If I am using zip(list1,list2) I am getting [] as output.

I don't want to use any method other than zip. Is there any way I could get the output using zip function?

Comment: no... you would at least need to use len or something (or izip longest... or just write your own version )

Comment: The zip() function returns a zip object, which is an iterator of tuples where the first item in each passed iterator is paired together, and then the second item in each passed iterator are paired together etc.

But you are expecting an iterable of number not tuple, You should use extend list1.extend(list2).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a function which can replace "zip" function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569341/is-there-a-function-which-can-replace-zip-function-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that zip is not used to achieve merging your lists

Here is the correct implementation

```
list1 = []
list2 = [0]
result=list1+list2
print(result)

# result output: [0]
```

However, zip function is used as an iterator between lists. below is an example to help you with the concept

```
a = ("1", "2", "3")
b = ("A", "B", "C")

x = zip(a, b)

for i in x:  # will loop through the items in x
    print(i)

# result output:  
# ('1', 'A')
# ('2', 'B')
# ('3', 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

the zip method is not ment for that. just use the addition or the extend method

```
a=[0,1]
b=[2,3]
c = a+b
c
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3]

a.extend([2,3])
a
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```